# Chosen js append search term to the drop down value

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-chosen

I am newbie in javascript and html5. I am trying to achieve the following:

I have a drop down with the below values:

```
Everything:
From:
To:
```

User will have a text box to enter the search term. When the user enters a text like "blah" and selects "From:" in the drop down and hits enter, the text in the text box should say 
"From: blah" and searches all the messages from Blah.

This is a feature in Outlook that i am trying to implement. I have tried to use chosen js but could not proceed much. Could anyone provide any pointers?

Comment: give us your codes...

Comment: Please do show some code. Also, Select2 is a better-supported fork of Chosen: http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/

Answer (score 0):

Assume this is your html:

```
<select id="cmbClause">
  <option value="1">Everything:</option>
  <option value="2">From:</option>
  <option value="3">To:</option>
</select>
<input type="text" id="txtSearch" />
<input type="text" id="txtResult" />
```

Then try jQuery script below:

```
$(function(){
  $('#txtSearch').keypress(function(e) {
    // if user press "Enter" on txtSearch and txtSearch not empty
    if(e.keyCode==13 && $('#txtSearch').val().trim()!="") {
      $('#txtResult').val(setClause($('#cmbClause').val()) + $('#txtSearch').val());
    }
  });

  function setClause(val) {// Get select (dropdown) value and return string
    var clause;
    switch(val) {
      case '1': clause = "Everything "; break;
      case '2': clause = "From "; break;
      case '3': clause = "To "; break;
    }
    return clause;
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks...that may not solve the whole problem...but provided me the kick start i was looking for.